# Creating a MongoDB Replica Set Service in DreamFactory

Tags: mongodb, service, connection, replication

I'm trying to create a Service using a MongoDB Replica Set. MongoDB's docs says [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) that the connection string format has to be

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

So, my connection string is something like

```
mongodb://IP1:PORT1,IP2:PORT2,IP3:PORT3/DATABASE?replicaSet=REPLICA_SET_NAME
```

But when I try to explore the service, I'm not getting any data, collection or schema and I noticed that DreamFactory created another database called "DATABASE?replicaSet=REPLICA_SET_NAME". I tried to just remove these options "replicaSet=REPLICA_SET_NAME" to see what happens and then I'm getting this error while I explore:

```
{
  "error": [
    {
      "context": null,
      "message": "Failed to list resources for this service.\nIP1:PORT1: not master and slaveOk=false",
      "code": 500
    }
  ]
}
```

If I keep trying to explore the same REST Endpoint (for instance, /rest/API-NAME?names_only=true&include_schemas=true), then I eventually get the correct response. It seems that it tries with a different ip and port every time I make the request.

I also noticed that if I just leave the primary server and remove the options from the connection string, then it works fine. But this is pointless, because I'm losing the whole replica set point.

I even tried to set a lookup key with the name "replicaSet" equals to REPLICA_SET_NAME, but it didn't work either.

How can I use MongoDB replica sets with DreamFactory?

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the solution to your problem but I have few observations.

Techically, your connection string are fine. But what I have found in DreamFactory is, they don't seem to allow options with the connection string. They seem to allow only authentication and database name in connection string. It is considering "DATABASE?replicaSet=REPLICA_SET_NAME" as the database name because they only allow database name in the URI.

This is info box text below the text field to enter the connection string in DreamFactory - "The connection string can include authentication credentials as well as database name. If they contain special characters, please enter them below."

Looks like they meant, "only authentication credentials as well as database name."

When you remove the option "replicaSet=REPLICA_SET_NAME", then you get the desired database name. But since you have replicaset nodes in connection, it will pick one server from them and connect to it. If it connects to primary node things work well as you can read and write to primary node. If it happens to chooses a node that is not primary then you have "Failed to list resources for this service.\nIP1:PORT1: not master and slaveOk=false" error.

The only condition when this should work is -
1. You connect only to the primary node, just to avoid connecting to secondaries.
2. you pass only the database name, just to escape messing up the database name

That's why it works when you just leave the primary server and also remove the options from connection string.

Comment: That's not a solution. Changing the read preference may have far reaching consequences due to the fact that MongoDB has eventual consistency only.